# Generate "nice" random matrix

Tags: matrix, random, conditional

I don't frequent this community, so please give criticism if this is a poor question.

I am trying to make a tool which generates a small (say, $4\times 4$) matrix with integer entries, which has a "nice" Jordan normal form — i.e., one that can be computed by hand. The purpose is for manual practice.

Here is what I have:

```
  A := RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}] (*This generates a random 4×4 matrix*)
  Dynamic[MatrixForm[A]] (*This is the random matrix*)
  Dynamic[MatrixForm[Part[JordanDecomposition[A], 2]]] (*Here is its Jordan Normal form*)
```

As it is, about $1$ in $10$ of these matrices has relatively nice Jordan Normal form, and that is with random entries of $-1,\,0$, and $1$. Complex eigenvalues are fine, but obviously eigenvalues like `Root[#^4 - #^2 + 3 # + 2 &, 1]` are intractable.

The easiest solution here would be to somehow loop the random generator until the entries in the final output are rational complex numbers. I have tried and failed to use conditional statements to achieve this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you generate some nice random matrices, treat them as a Jordan decomposition and create a matrix that should return them?

Comment: Why do you say things like `Root[#^4-#^2+3 #+2&, 1]` are intractable? They're perfectly good algebraic constants. The `Root` representation has nice properties. For example, real `Root` constants don't grow parasitic imaginary parts when evaluated numerically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create random matrices until the eigenvalues do not have a [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) form:

```
While[
    A = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}];
    !FreeQ[RootReduce @ Eigenvalues[A], _Root]
];

Eigenvalues[A]
JordanDecomposition[A][[2]]
```

> {-2, I Sqrt[2], -I Sqrt[2], 0}
>
> {{-2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -I Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, 0, 0, I Sqrt[2]}}

Comment: Beautiful. "While" is exactly what I was looking for; thanks.

Comment: Beginner question: how can I check against two forms in the eigenvalues? For example, I cannot see how to use FreeQ to check for both "Root" and "Sqrt."

Comment: @ElliotG That's a bit tricky. Use `|` to have multiple patterns, but the pattern for `Sqrt` is not `_Sqrt` it is `Power[_, 1/2]`. So, you could use `FreeQ[expr, _Root | Power[_, _Rational]]`

Answer (score 8):

I'll present another method to generate "nice" random matrices. I make no claims on the distribution followed by the matrices from my procedure.

This method has three steps:

1. use `RandomInteger[]` to generate the eigenvalues, and randomly convert clusters of identical eigenvalues into Jordan blocks
2. reduce a random integer matrix to [Hermite normal form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteNormalForm.html) and take its [unimodular factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnimodularMatrix.html)
3. multiply the generated matrices appropriately

An implementation might look like this:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["jordan", Method -> "ExtendedCA"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            With[{n = 4 (* matrix size *), erange = {-2, 2} (* range of eigenvalues *)},
                 vm = First[HermiteDecomposition[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]]];
                 jm = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] ->
                                  (If[Length[#] == 1, {#}, 
                                      DiagonalMatrix[#] +
                                      DiagonalMatrix[RandomInteger[1, Length[#] - 1],
                                                     1]] & /@ 
                                   Split[Sort[RandomInteger[erange, n]]])];
                 mat = Inverse[vm].jm.vm]];

MatrixForm[mat]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 -2 & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Check the Jordan form:

```
MatrixForm /@ JordanDecomposition[mat]
```

$$\{\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}\}$$